# Replace all items in list within text file

Tags: r, notepad++, opennlp

I am trying to create training data for the openNLP name finder and would appreciate any help that you might be able to offer.

If I had a text file like this:

```
Pierre Vinken, 61 years old, will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29. 
John Smith is chairman of Elsevier N.V., the Dutch publishing group.
```

and a list of names in a second file such as:

```
Pierre Vinken
John Smith
```

Would there be a way to find all mentions of the names within the text file and tag them appropriately within the file to create the training data, such that the file now reads like:

```
<START:CEO> Pierre Vinken <END>, 61 years old, will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29. 
<START:CEO> John Smith <END> is chairman of Elsevier N.V., the Dutch publishing group.
```

Note that I am aware that other pre-processing steps will be necessary to make the file appropriate for training, such as forcing the data into one sentence per line.

I would appreciate a solution that is in Notepad++ or R, but I also have access to shell tools as necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
#using R
x1<-"Pierre Vinken, 61 years old, will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29. John Smith is chairman of Elsevier N.V., the Dutch publishing group."
y1<-c("Pierre Vinken","John Smith")
y2<-paste0("<START:CEO> ",y1[1:2]," <END>")
library(qdap)
mgsub(y1,y2,x1)
[1] "<START:CEO> Pierre Vinken <END>, 61 years old, will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29.<START:CEO> John Smith <END> is chairman of Elsevier N.V., the Dutch publishing group."
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using **qdapRegex** (which I maintain).  This uses base `gsub` (using a grouping approach) and **qdapRegex** is unnecessary but I like the ease of the ease of use for `group` and `pastex` (I show how to use pure base here as well).  This makes one regular expression s no need for `mgsub`.  This may be slower though as it uses `fixed = FALSE` whereas `mgsub` uses `fixed = TRUE`.

```
x1<-"Pierre Vinken, 61 years old, will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29. John Smith is chairman of Elsevier N.V., the Dutch publishing group."
y1<-c("Pierre Vinken", "John Smith")

## pacman used to load and if missing install qdapRegex
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(qdapRegex)

gsub(pastex(group(y1)), "<START:CEO> \\1 <END>", x1, perl=TRUE)

## [1] "<START:CEO> Pierre Vinken <END>, 61 years old, will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29. <START:CEO>  <END> is chairman of Elsevier N.V., the Dutch publishing group."
```

**Pure base**

```
gsub(paste(sprintf("(%s)", y1), collapse="|"), 
    "<START:CEO> \\1 <END>", x1, perl=TRUE)
```